# Ruby:-- Accept array as input and put it into hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

User must enter the array as input. Hash has to accept the input array elements as values.

Create a Ruby program for this by using loops. If array completed print this statement “All array elements are assigned to keys in the hash”

```
A = [1, 6, 4, 5]
H = {“k1” => 1
“k2” => 6
“k3” => 4
“k4” => 5}
```

Comment: 1):-User must enter the array as input.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be,

```
a.each_with_index.inject({}) { |m,(a,i)| m["k#{i+1}"] = a; m }
```

**Update:** answering to your question

```
puts 'Enter number of hash elements'
n = gets.to_i
n.times |i|
    hash["k#{i+1}"] = gets.to_i
end
puts 'All array elements are assigned to keys in the hash'
```

Comment: You can use `each_with_object` and get rid of returning `m`  `a.each_with_object({}).with_index { |(a,m), i| m["k#{i+1}"] = a }`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yeah, it is better than I gave, thanks :)

Comment: case is i am getting array from user input, Then, create an empty hash = H=Hash.new{}. After that i need to iterate through that array(user input) and put values into hash values.

Comment: Using for loop only

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1, 6, 4, 5]
Hash[[*'k1'.."k#{A.length}"].zip(A)]
```

Comment: Case is i am getting array from user input, Then, create an empty hash = H=Hash.new{}. After that i need to iterate through that array(user input) and put values into hash values

Comment: Using for loop only